# Android API level < 19 and "try can use automatic resource management" warning

Tags: android, try-catch, suppress-warnings

I have this piece of code

```
private void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {

    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();

    try {

        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);

    }finally {

        if(inChannel != null) {

            inChannel.close();

        }

        outChannel.close();

    }

}
```

that generates the annoying warning "try can use automatic resource management". The prolem is I cannot use Java 7 try-with-resources cause my app targets api level 14 (got an error if I use it). Is there a way to suppress that annoying warning?

Comment: Use a SuppressLint on it

Comment: and what id should I use? I don't want to use "all"..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

@SuppressWarnings("TryFinallyCanBeTryWithResources") did the trick :)

Comment: this just removes the warning, but it will not work on real devices <19

Comment: So any suggestion? @huluyige

Comment: @KaKa do not use "try-with-resources" of java 7 :)

Comment: You can do "Analyze / Inspect Code" and then turn off the inspection for the statement in the dialog.  As of AS2.2RC, I got this: `//noinspection TryFinallyCanBeTryWithResources`added above the  `try` line.   Agreed it is pretty annoying to get this Lint warning when the min level is set to 16, and the feature is only available at 19!

Answer (score 0):

`@SuppressLint("NewApi")` also will work =)

And for example:

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static File saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File file = null;
        if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
            file = new File(getFolderStorageDirectory(), getFileNameImage());
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried this, but the lint warning kept showing up anyway. I had to use `TryFinallyCanBeTryWithResources` instead of `NewApi`.